# Text transform to uppercase via CSS?

Tags: apache-flex

Am I right, that Flex doesn't support HTML like text transform?

```
s|Panel #titleDisplay {
  textAlign: center;
  textTransform: uppercase;
  fontSize: 16px;
}
```

Comment: It seems you are - Flex Builder's auto-complete doesn't show text-transform property.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Spark, you can do that with the the `spark.components.Label` and the related text components:

```
s|Label
{
  typographicCase: lowercaseToSmallCaps
}
```

The options for that are:

```
capsToSmallCaps
default
lowercase
lowercaseToSmallCaps
uppercase
```

Not sure if that's equivalent to `textTransform`, but it works!